# pointer argument becomes a null pointer when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I have a function which takes a pointer to a struct

```
node *found = nbitree.findnode(nbitree.base_node, 15);
```

The 'nbitree.base_node' is what is becoming a 0x0 pointer. I have a feeling im not handling this pointer correctly, but im not sure how to fix it.

nbitree.base_node is created like so:

```
struct node {
    int load;
    node *parent{0};
    node *left{0};
    node *right{0};
};

//...in the Bitree class

base_node = new node;
```

with the function being declared as

```
node *Bitree::findnode(node *nd, int value){
    if (nd->load == value){
        return nd;
    } else if (findnode(nd->left, value) != 0){
        return findnode(nd->left, value);
    } else if (findnode(nd->right, value) != 0){
        return findnode(nd->right, value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have debugged the code and the base_node is populated and holds a valid pointer, but whenever i try to copy it or pass it i get a null pointer. This code does compile without any errors or warnings.

### Expand

- the code was edited earlier to expand the findnode function
- The program crashes when it tried to check the if statement '(nd->load == value)'
- It is compiled with the -O0 flag

Comment: Where is he code for `findnode`?

Comment: Please post your tree function(s) as well. Nothing could be fruitfully commented out seeing this only.

Comment: Also show us what test you're using to determine that `base_node` is changing into a null pointer.

Comment: `node *left{0};`: what is this, is this some new syntax feature I am not aware of ?

Comment: @kebs it initializes to 0

Comment: @MikeDeSimone i used the debugger to step into the code and check the values.

Comment: Ho, I see. I just learned a new C++11 feature.

Comment: If you're using a debugger, make sure you compiled with optimization off (`-O0`). Optimizations tend to confuse debuggers, since they can do things like make variables disappear.

Comment: @EdHeal: It's right there...? Edited 10 minutes ago.

Comment: ... and gone. Wat. If it's crashing on `(nd->load == value)` then it's almost certain that `nd` isn't a valid pointer; either it's null or it's pointing at freed (or never-allocated) memory.

Comment: yes nd is never given a valid value, so it is null. I think im going wrong in how im passing the argument(see second line of OP)

Comment: You haven't finished your debugging yet, as evidenced by the fact that you have failed to construct and present a testcase. Finish your debugging, then come back to us.

Answer (score 2):

Something I noticed: This code:

```
node *Bitree::findnode(node *nd, int value){
    if (nd->load == value){
        return nd;
    } else if (findnode(nd->left, value) != 0){
        return findnode(nd->left, value);
    } else if (findnode(nd->right, value) != 0){
        return findnode(nd->right, value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

has redundant function calls. You rerun the find in the tree branch that the node was found in. Better would be to keep track of results so you only call `findnode` on a subtree once:

```
node *Bitree::findnode(node *nd, int value){
    if (nd->load == value) return nd;
    node* f = findnode(nd->left, value);
    if(f) return f;
    return findnode(nd->right, value);
}
```

Of course, if your node values were stored sorted in the tree, like in most binary trees, you wouldn't need to try both branches, and would actually get O(logN) performance:

```
node *Bitree::findnode(node *nd, int value) {
    while(nd) {
        if(nd->load == value) return nd;
        if(nd->load < value) nd = nd->left;
        else nd = nd->right;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even better to replace `return 0;` with `return nullptr`;

Comment: Yes, i did realize this. I had it marked for a rework, the code as it stands, is used for experimenting with various ideas and is in an 'ugly' state. Since i wrote it while drunk. Ill definitely be looking to implement it the way you've shown.

Comment: Writing code while drunk? You're brave.

Comment: PFft it's writing code while sober that requires bravery.

Comment: That explains so much.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone - When will they fit computers/mobile phones with breath analysers. Would sometime save me from myself phoning old boyfriends up at stupid hours :->

Comment: Not effective; you'd hack in a workaround.